# Problema ao conectar em banco de dados Firebird

Tags: php, sql, firebird

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pessoal, estou com um projeto para fazer um relatório que faz uma pesquisa em um banco firebird e estou com o arquivo .FB pronto para criar o banco. Porém, na conexão com o dbschema ele me apresenta esse erro de driver. Pesquisei na internet e nao consegui resolver. Alguém tem uma luz?

Comment: Qual ferramenta está utilizando para conexão ao BD? Verificou se o processo do Firebird está executando normalmente?

Comment: agradeço a ajuda! Ja foi resolvido, esqueci de pontuar

Comment: Você poderia responder sua própria pergunta informando qual a solução utilizou para que a pergunta não fique sem resposta.

Comment: Obrigado! nao sabia dessa possibilidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei outro gerenciador, aparentemente o problema era o DBchema q nao reconhecia os drivers do firebird, utilizei o IBExpert e funcionou corretamente